# What does the '^' mean in this Windows batch snippet?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

The batch snippet is:

```
for /f %%i in ('driverquery /si ^| findstr /C:"QD1000_RS232_DRIVER"') do set USB_DRIVER_FOUND=%%i
```

So what does the `^` mean?

I tried to run part of the command:

```
driverquery /si ^| findstr /C:"QD1000_RS232_DRIVER"
```

But failed:

```
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '|'.
Type "DRIVERQUERY /?" for usage.
```

### ADD 1:

The explanation of `^`: (search for ^)

http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the escape character. It escapes the pipe so you can put it in the string quotes `'  '` without the shell trying to use it as a pipe. To run it directly would be

```
driverquery /si | findstr /C:"QD1000_RS232_DRIVER"
```